# AngularAMD, Dynamic UI-Router, RequireJS - "Error: 'MyDashboardCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router, angular-amd

**Intro:**

I recognize that this is really deep and I won't probably get any help here but I have exhausted what seems like the entire Internet for a solution.

The short of it is **I want to make my ui-router dynamic, and with that the controllers, WHILE USING REQUIREJS**.

I know Dan Wahlin has something similar but he hard codes his controllers in his main.js file and **I'd much prefer keep everything related to $state.routes come from a DB, ie. template & controller**.

**This is the error I am getting:**

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyDashboardCtrl' is not a function, got
>   undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/ng/areq?p0=MyDashboardCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

I know the problem is that Dashboard controller is not being cached even though it is in the ui-router as the default route.

While the Dashboard.html is appearing, via the **ui-view="container"**, the controller is just not being cached.

[image]

**main.js:**

> ```
> require.config({
>
> baseUrl: "/app",
> paths: {
>     'app' : '/app/app',
>     'jquery': '/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
>     'angular': '/vendor/angular/angular',
>     'angular-bootstrap': '/vendor/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min',
>     'angular-breeze': '/vendor/breeze.js.labs/breeze.angular',
>     'angular-cookies': '/vendor/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min',
>     'angular-resource': '/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.min',
>     'angular-route': '/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min',
>     'angular-sanitize': '/vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min',
>     'angular-touch': '/vendor/angular-touch/angular-touch.min',
>     'angular-ui-router':'/vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min',
>     'angular-ui-tree':'/vendor/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree.min',
>     'angularAMD': '/vendor/angularAMD/angularAMD.min',
>     'bootstrap':'/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min',
>     'breeze':'/vendor/breeze/breeze.min',
>     'breeze-directives':'/vendor/breeze.js.labs/breeze.directives',
>     'highcharts':'/vendor/highcharts/highcharts',
>     'highchartsng':'/vendor/highcharts/highcharts-ng',
>     'moment': '/vendor/moment/min/moment.min',
>     'ngload': '/vendor/ng-load/ng-load',
>     'q': '/vendor/q/q',
>     'spin': '/vendor/javascripts/jquery.spin',
>     'toastr': '/vendor/toastr/toastr.min',
>     'tweenMax':'/vendor/greensock/src/minified/TweenMax.min',
>     'underscore':'/vendor/underscore/underscore.min'
> },
>
> // Add angular modules that does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
> shim: {
>     angular: {
>         exports: "angular"
>     },
>     'angularAMD': ['angular'],
>     'angular-ui-router':['angular'],
>     'highchartsng': {deps:['highcharts']},
>     'bootstrap': {deps:['jquery']},
>     'toastr': {deps:['jquery']}
> },
>
> // kick start application
> deps: ['app'] });
> ```

**app.js:**

> ```
> define(['angularAMD', 'angular-ui-router', 'config/common', 
>             'layout/services/dBoardSvc', 'localize/LangSettings.Svc'], 
> function (angularAMD, common, dBoardSvc, LangSettingsSvc) {
>
> var $stateProviderRef = null;
> var $urlRouterProviderRef = null;
>
> var app = angular.module("anuApp", ['ui.router'])
>     /* @ngInject */
>     .config(function ($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
>         $urlRouterProviderRef = $urlRouterProvider;
>         $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;
>         $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
>         $urlRouterProviderRef.otherwise('/')
>     })
>     /* @ngInject */
>     .run(function($q, $rootScope, $state, $window, common, dBoardSvc, LangSettingsSvc){
>         // set initial current language
>         LangSettingsSvc.currentLang = LangSettingsSvc.languages[0];
>         dBoardSvc.all().success(function (data) {
>             var startUp = undefined;
>             angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
>                 var tmp = 6;
>                 angular.forEach(value.viewGroups, function (viewGroup, key) {
>                     angular.forEach(viewGroup.viewStates, function (viewState, key) {
>                         var viewStateUrl = undefined;
>                         if (viewState.isStartUp == true && startUp == undefined) {
>                             startUp = viewState.name;
>                         }
>
>                         if (viewState.url != '0') {
>                             viewStateUrl = viewState.name + "/:moduleId";
>                         }
>
>                         var state = {
>                             "url": viewStateUrl,
>                             "parent": viewState.parentName,
>                             "abstract": viewState.isAbstract,
>                             "views": {}
>                         };
>
>                         angular.forEach(viewState.views, function (view) {
>                             state.views[view.name] = {
>                                 controller: view.controllerName,
>                                 templateUrl: common.appRoot +  view.templateUrl + '.html',
>                                 controllerUrl: common.appRoot +  view.controllerUrl + '.js'
>                             };
>
>                         });
>                         $stateProviderRef.state(viewState.name, angularAMD.route(state));
>      --------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  **console.log(state);**
>                     });
>                 });
>             });
>             $state.go(startUp);
>         });
>     });
> // Bootstrap Angular when DOM is ready    
> angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
> return app; });
> ```

[image]

**DashboardCtrl:**

> ```
> define(['app'], function (app) {
> 'use strict';
>
> app.register.controller('MyDashboardCtrl', MyDashboardCtrl);
>
> /* @ngInject */
> function MyDashboardCtrl($scope){
>     $scope.pageTitle = 'MyDashboardCtrl';
> };
> ```
>
> });

**Conclusion:**

Could this be some time of resolve issue? I am literally grasping for straws here and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem was with my controller, below is the correct approach:**

> ```
> define(['angularAMD'], function (app) {
> 'use strict'
>
>  /* @ngInject */  
> app.controller('MyDashboardCtrl', MyDashboardCtrl);
> function MyDashboardCtrl($scope) {
>     $scope.pageTitle = 'This controller now loads dynamically';
> };
>
> // MyDashboardCtrl.$inject = ['$scope']; 
> });
> ```

**NOTHING is hard coded in my app short of vendor files. My controllers, my views and my services are all dynamic & authorization based!!!**

[image]

I hope this helps others because the implications of being able to utilize requirejs with dynamic routes means that not only does one :

1. Minimize the javaScript to only that which the view needs, but by coupling it with dynamic views & a login,
2. One can effectively hide all client side scripts that a respective user may not have authority to acccess.

I just wish examples were more than 'Hello World' these days ;(